# I have installed oxford advanced learner's dictionary ver 9 on bluestacks, but there are font problems

Tags: fonts, bluestacks

I have installed Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary ver 9 in Bluestacks, but I am having I guess some font issues in the display:
[image]

as you can see in the above screenshot taken from Bluestacks running OALD 9, there are some unwanted squares.
I don't have the same problem in my android tablet.
Does anybody know how to solve this?